# Separate data and domain layers in a multi-module project and follow D in Solid

Tags: android, solid-principles, clean-architecture, multi-module, dependency-inversion

I have a multi-module project where I want to separate data and domain logics from each other in two different modules. (At the moment they are all in core module) : https://github.com/alirezaeiii/TMDb-Compose-Playground

I have a logic for supporting pagination in different screen in my app :

```
private const val STARTING_PAGE_INDEX = 1

abstract class BasePagingSource<T : TMDbItem>(private val context: Context) : PagingSource<Int, T>() {

    protected abstract suspend fun fetchItems(page: Int): List<T>

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, T> {
        val page = params.key ?: STARTING_PAGE_INDEX
        return try {
            val response = fetchItems(page)
            LoadResult.Page(
                data = response,
                prevKey = if (page == STARTING_PAGE_INDEX) null else page - 1,
                nextKey = if (response.isEmpty()) null else page + 1
            )
        } catch (exception: IOException) {
            LoadResult.Error(TMDbException(context.getString(R.string.failed_loading_msg)))
        } catch (exception: HttpException) {
            LoadResult.Error(TMDbException(context.getString(R.string.failed_loading_msg)))
        }
    }

    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, T>): Int? {
        return state.anchorPosition?.let {
            state.closestPageToPosition(it)?.prevKey?.plus(1)
                ?: state.closestPageToPosition(it)?.nextKey?.minus(1)
        }
    }
}
```

And I have a base repository class :

```
abstract class BasePagingRepository<T : TMDbItem> {

    protected abstract fun pagingSource(query: String?): BasePagingSource<T>

    fun fetchResultStream(query: String?= null): Flow<PagingData<T>> = Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(pageSize = NETWORK_PAGE_SIZE),
        pagingSourceFactory = { pagingSource(query) }
    ).flow

    companion object {
        private const val NETWORK_PAGE_SIZE = 20
    }
}
```

The issue with this approach is all sub classes extend this as the same :

```
@Singleton
class AiringTodayTvSeriesPagingRepository @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val context: Context,
    private val tvShowApi: TVShowService
) : BasePagingRepository<TVShow>() {

    override fun pagingSource(query: String?): BasePagingSource<TVShow> =
        AiringTodayTvSeriesPagingSource(context, tvShowApi)
}
```

Or :

```
@Singleton
class OnTheAirTvSeriesPagingRepository @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val context: Context,
    private val tvShowApi: TVShowService
) : BasePagingRepository<TVShow>() {

    override fun pagingSource(query: String?): BasePagingSource<TVShow> =
        OnTheAirTvSeriesPagingSource(context, tvShowApi)
}
```

and etc in com.sample.tmdb.core.data.repository package in core module. So they all for instance extend `BasePagingRepository<TVShow>`. Of-course I have used dependency injection for repositories :

```
    @Singleton
    @Binds
    internal abstract fun bindTrendingTVShowRepository(trendingTvSeriesPagingRepository: TrendingTvSeriesPagingRepository): BasePagingRepository<TVShow>

    @Singleton
    @Binds
    internal abstract fun bindPopularTVShowRepository(popularTvSeriesPagingRepository: PopularTvSeriesPagingRepository): BasePagingRepository<TVShow>

    @Singleton
    @Binds
    internal abstract fun bindAiringTodayTVShowRepository(airingTodayTvSeriesPagingRepository: AiringTodayTvSeriesPagingRepository): BasePagingRepository<TVShow>

    @Singleton
    @Binds
    internal abstract fun bindOnTheAirTVShowRepository(onTheAirTvSeriesPagingRepository: OnTheAirTvSeriesPagingRepository): BasePagingRepository<TVShow>
```

So when I want to inject these repositories in my ViewModels, I have to use concrete implementation rather than abstraction or interface (`Dependency inversion` in Solid) such as :

```
@HiltViewModel
class AiringTodayTvSeriesViewModel @Inject constructor(repository: AiringTodayTvSeriesPagingRepository) :
    BaseMainPagingViewModel<TVShow>(repository)
```

So 1st of all I did not follow Dependency inversion and 2nd I have to add both `data` and `domain` module dependency to my feature modules. Which I think would not be good and it should be enough to just add `domain` dependency as my interface and abstract repositories are there.

How do you approach to solve this issue? I appreciate for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I concluded to use qualifier annotations for this purpose while I am using Hilt, such as :

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
@Qualifier
annotation class Discover
```

In the di module, I have used it as follow :

```
    @Singleton
    @Discover
    @Binds
    internal abstract fun bindDiscoverMoviesRepository(discoverMoviesPagingRepository: DiscoverMoviesPagingRepository): BasePagingRepository<Movie>
```

And simply I used the annotation in the ViewModel :

```
@HiltViewModel
class DiscoverMoviesViewModel @Inject constructor(
    @Discover repository: BasePagingRepository<Movie>
) : BaseMainPagingViewModel<Movie>(repository)
```